# Is it possible to nest transactions with TransactionManager?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, lazy-initialization

I have the following code:

```
public ResultProcessDTO process() {
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(this.transactionManager);
    transactionTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    return transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
       ...
       SomeEntity entity = service.findById(id);
       ...
       otherBean.someMethod();
       ...
    });
}
```

And, in another bean:

```
public void someMethod() {
    ...
    service.save(entity);
}
```

I need `someMethod()` to be `REQUIRES_NEW`, to perform the save and commit the transaction regardless of what happens with the rest of the `process()`.

I've already tried `@Transactional` to leave this up to Spring, but the `process()` is triggered via KafkaListener, which leads me to have problems with lazy load entities that are fetched along the way.
For example, if I call `entity.getChildList()` I get a `LazyInitializationException`. This exception is not thrown if I use TransactionTemplate.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or how to make it work as I hope?